# New API - add a task to a board?

Tags: quire-api

I'm so excited to have an `API`, but I can't find a `hook` for my one requirement.  Can you add a task to a board via the `API`?  Or find tasks by `column/board`?

Thanks,
Dan Scully

Answer (score 2):

you can [Update an existing task](https://quire.io/dev/api/#operation--task--oid--put) and assign specific board using:

PUT
url: /task/{OID}
body: {board: {BOARD_OID}}

at the moment this function seems undocumented (I'll inform the maintainer, as well as suggest a feature to search tasks by BOARD_OID)

**UPDATE 2019-10-14:**

- [the documentation](https://quire.io/dev/api/#operation--task--oid--put) now contains the field `board`
- please also watch [quire-api#7](https://github.com/quire-api/quire-api/issues/7) (regarding search-by-board)